# character pointers(allotted by new) and their initialistaion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, new-operator

i have some doubts regarding character pointers:

1.when we write the declaration:

```
char *t;
```

do we need to do

```
t=new char[6];
strcpy(t,"terry");
```

or directly

```
 t="terry";
```

will do..

2.Also if we follow do

```
char *t;
t=new char[6];
t="terry";
```

will t now point to the allocated memory from heap or the first letter of terry(if we look from the point of view of manipulation of pointers).

3.if i write:

```
char *t;
```

and then i have to initialise 't' to '\0'(but t should point to an allocated memory space)..how do i do this because my mvc 2010 compiler doesnt allow...

```
t=new char[5](0);//0 is the ascii value of '\0'
```

Comment: Just don't use `char*`, use `std::string` instead (`std::vector<char>` if you're feeling really rebellious).

Comment: Why are you writing code like this in C++?

Comment: BTW lol at `//0 is the ascii value of '\0'` :)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus...that just means avoiding the problems rather than solving them

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal...just wanted to make it clear why i used 0

Answer (score 3):

You're tagged C++. Use string:

`std::string t("terry");` and let the language take care of the details for you.

1. Either way will do, depending on your needs. If you need to change the string later you have to allocate the memory, and when you allocate always remember to delete it later.
2. The first letter of the literal.
3. `t=new char[5]; t[0] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do the latter option, but the pointer will most likely point to a read-only memory region, so you should only do that with a `const char *`.
2. In this case, t will ultimately point to a read-only memory region, leaking those 6 bytes.
3. You can use the `memset()` function to set a whole array to 0.

But yes, use `std::string` instead and stop thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shoudn't do the second, because `t` is `char*`, and so `t="terry"` is deprecated (and your compiler might give this warning  indicating the assignment statement.)
2. The allocated memory is leaked, since you didn't use it, and `t` points to `terry`. Again, this is deprecated (and your compiler might give this warning indicating the assignment statement).
3. Just do : `t = new char[5]();` It's default initialized now.

As the best practice, in general is, `std::string`. So use it:

```
std::string t = "terry";
```

No memory leak, no deprecated feature,  no warning. No tension.

Comment: @nawaz...i tried this... it doesnt work....error says for array initialisation curly braces are needed but even if i do {'\0'} another error crops up saying missing ';' before { and }..

Comment: @avinash: Ohh.. I was wrong. It's actually `t = new char[5]();`.

Comment: @nawaz...but this is simply a getaway for the '\0'  case...what if i wanted to initialise it to 'n' at all places.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If the string (e.g. "terry") is not going to get changed anywhere in you program, you can surely do

```
char* t = "terry";
```

and forget about the memory allocated for the string as it will be freed on its own. However, a better programming practice for constant strings would be declaring `t` as `const char*` like this:

```
const char* t = "terry";
```

But if it is going to get changed, then it's either

```
char* t = new char[6];
strcpy(t, "terry");
```

or

```
char t[6];
strcpy(t, "terry");
```

In the first case, where `new` operator is used, you will have to free the memory allocated with `new` after you no longer need the string:

```
delete[] t;
```

In the second case, the memory underlying the sting will be freed automatically when `t` leaves the C++ scope (curly braces) it was declared in (but if `t` is a member of an object, the memory will be freed only when the object is destructed).

**2.** After

```
char* t;
t = new char[6];
t = "terry";
```

`t` would really point at "terry", but the pointer/address you would need to free the memory allocated with `new` is lost for good.

**3.** String null terminators ('\0') are just like other characters: they need reside somewhere in the memory. You were wise enough to allocate 6 bytes for "terry", which is 5 characters in length: after

```
char* t = new char[6];
strcpy(t, "terry");
```

the 6th byte of the memory block pointed by `t` holds the null terminator. But

```
char* t;
```

does not allocate any memory apart from the `t` pointer. So, if you want a string to contain only a null terminator (be zero-length), you could do it in this way:

```
char* t = new char[1];
t[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: @desmond...but we do write int *y=new int(7).....to initialise the the  address pointed by y...cant we do that in case of an array

Comment: Yes, if not counting the `char* t = "terry"` way, you can combine memory allocation with its initialization in one C++ statement if you use memory from the stack (the `char t[6]` way) and not memory dynamically allocated with the `new` operator. Say you need an array of 4 characters all being nulls ('\0'), then you write: `char t[4] = {'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};`